# how to prevent tab button in form field and jump into another field?

Tags: javascript, html

Example : This is my Reservation Form and when i click tab button on keyword then it need to go first name,email,room type but prevent tab from arrival date and directly jump into depature date

[image]

and i tried like this from some stack overflow solution.When i click tab button in keyword then it should jump into Full name Field and Last Name Field and prevent tab from  tag and jump into direct Age Field.So Is there way to do like thi ?

```
       <input type="text" name="full name" class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control">
       <a href="{{ route('banks.index') }}" class=" block-tab ">Go to another Page</a>
       <input type="number" name="age">
       <button type="submit" >Save</button>

      <script>
         $('.block-tab').on('keydown', function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 9) e.preventDefault();
        });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tabindex="-1"` to skip an input field
for more information you can read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

```html
<input placeholder="ok"/></br>
<input placeholder="ok"/></br>
<input placeholder="skip" tabindex="-1"/></br>
<input placeholder="ok"/></br>
```